# Hugs !! Partial Application Bug

Tags: haskell, hugs

Hugs seems to have a problem with several non-enbraced `!!` in a partial application.

While this works fine in GHCi:

```
([[0]]!!0!!)0
```

Hugs reports a syntax error for the `)`.

**Is this a bug in Hugs?**

Adding an extra brace for the second list index operator works though:

```
(([[0]]!!)0!!)0
```

or

```
(([[0]]!!0)!!)0
```

Comment: I am not sure. I guess it's a different interpretation of the Haskell standards. This actually happens with every section where more than one operators appear on the lowest precedence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue in Hugs. From the [Hugs 98 Users Guide](http://cvs.haskell.org/Hugs/pages/users_guide/haskell98.html) section on Expressions:

> In Hugs, the expression must be an `fexp` (or `case` or `do`). Legal expressions like `(a+b+)` and `(a*b+)` are rejected.

**Digression Alert**

Maybe this is what `FUZxxl` was talking about in his comment?

Try defining your own `(!!)` function in `ghc` and set it to have right-associative fixity:

```
import Prelude hiding ((!!))
infixr 5 !! -- infixr will make it right associative
(!!) a b = head . drop b $ a
```

Now that line won't work in `ghci` either!

```
ghci> :t ([[0]] !! 0 !!)

<interactive>:1:1:
    The operator `!!' [infixr 5] of a section
        must have lower precedence than that of the operand,
          namely `!!' [infixr 5]
        in the section: `[[0]] !! 0 !!'
```

Because `(!!)` has been set with `infixr` and is now right-associative. If you use `infixl`, that line works fine.

This is a completely separate issue from the question you asked though. This is about left vs right associativity, whereas the problem with Hugs is that it just doesn't parse an expression like `(a+b+)`.