# Haskell: Why I can load this file in ghci but when I try to do the same in hugs I get a syntax error?

Tags: haskell, ghci, hugs

This is the file I am trying to load:

```
import Data.List (foldl')
import Text.Printf (printf)
import Data.Char (ord)

--data IntParsedStr = Int | ParsingError
--data ParsingError = ParsingError String

asInt :: String -> Either String Integer
asInt "" = Left "Empty string"
asInt xs@(x:xt) | x == '-' = either Left (Right . ((-1) *)) (asInt' xt)
                | otherwise = either Left Right (asInt' xs)
                where asInt' :: String -> Either String Integer
                      asInt' "" = Left "No digits"
                      asInt' xs = foldl' step (Right 0) xs
                                where step :: Either String Integer -> Char -> Either String Integer
                                      step (Left e) _ = Left e
                                      step (Right ac) c = either Left (Right . (10 * ac + ) . fromIntegral) (charAsInt c)

charAsInt :: Char -> Either String Int
charAsInt c | between (ord '0') (ord c) (ord '9') = Right $ ord c - ord '0'
            | otherwise = Left $ printf "'%c' is not a digit" c

checkPrecision str = either error ((str == ). show) (asInt str)

between :: Ord t => t -> t -> t -> Bool
between a b c = a <= b && b <= c
```

It loads without any problem in ghci but in hugs I get this error:

> ERROR "folds.hs":17 - Syntax error in expression (unexpected `)')

Line 17 is the last in the definition of asInt function

**Edit:**

Hi!
I recently founded that this is in fact a known hugs issue as said in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9874226/hugs-partial-application-bug)
where there is a link to the [Hugs 98 Users Guide](http://cvs.haskell.org/Hugs/pages/users_guide/haskell98.html) where says that

> Legal expressions like (a+b+) and (a*b+) are rejected.

Comment: I'm guessing it's the `(10 * ac + )`... what happens when you do `((10 * ac) + )`? (I can't test right now, so I don't want to answer the question)

Comment: It works! Thanks! However, is weird that one interpreter consider that that is a syntax error while the other dont.

Comment: GHC is known to be more liberal than the standard mandates in many cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is a bug in Hugs, not a liberality of GHC. The Haskell 98 report (appropriate in the context of Hugs usage) says

> Syntactic precedence rules apply to sections as follows. `(op e)` is legal if and only if `(x op e)` parses in the same way as `(x op (e))`; and similarly for `(e op)`. For example, `(*a+b)` is syntactically invalid, but `(+a*b)` and `(*(a+b))` are valid. Because (+) is left associative, `(a+b+)` is syntactically correct, but `(+a+b)` is not; the latter may legally be written as `(+(a+b))`.

I interpret that as allowing `(10 * ac + )` since both `(*)` and `(+)` are left associative, and indeed `(*)` has higher precedence.

As pointed out in the comments, `((10 * ac) + )` is accepted by both, so is a workaround.

Interestingly, this isn't listed in the [Hugs vs Haskell 98 page](http://cvs.haskell.org/Hugs/pages/users_guide/haskell98.html), so maybe Mark P. Jones reads this section of the report differently to me. Certainly I can forgive him for this; Gofer implemented constructor classes long before Haskell allowed them, and Hugs is still faster than GHCi at compilation, and still gives better error messages.